# Trying to send the file name as a prop to a child component using Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I am not sure what's wrong with my code. I expected to update the constant 'sounds', but I have tried many methods and the value of the 'sounds' property still doesn't change according to the database

```
  const computed = {
    sounds: {
      get() {
        return this.mcollection1Data.value;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.mcollection1Data.value = value;
      }
    }
  };
```

Below is full code

```
<script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
  import axios from 'axios';
  import playsound from './playsound.vue'
   
  const sounds = ref([]); 

  const collection1Data = ref([]);
  const collection2Data = ref([]);
  const mcollection1Data = ref([]);
  const mcollection2Data = ref([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const [collection1Response, collection2Response] = await Promise.all([
      axios.get('https://koh-xyn.com:50100/onboardshows'),
      axios.get('https://koh-xyn.com:50100/onboardlands'),
    ]);
    collection1Data.value = collection1Response.data;
    collection2Data.value = collection2Response.data;

    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    const filteredData1 = collection1Response.data.filter(doc => {
      const updatedTime = new Date(doc.updatedAt).getTime();
      return currentTime - updatedTime < 20 * 1000;
    });
    const filteredData2 = collection2Response.data.filter(doc => {
      const updatedTime = new Date(doc.updatedAt).getTime();
      return currentTime - updatedTime < 20 * 1000;
    });

    mcollection1Data.value = filteredData1;
    mcollection2Data.value = filteredData2;
  };

  const computed = {
    sounds: {
      get() {
        return this.mcollection1Data.value;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.mcollection1Data.value = value;
      }
    }
  };

  onMounted(() => {
    fetchData();
    setInterval(fetchData, 1000);
  });
  
        
  const isRecentlyUpdated = (updatedAt) => {
    const updatedTime = new Date(updatedAt);
    return (Date.now() - updatedTime.getTime()) < 15000;
  };

</script>
```

Comment: `set(value) {
  mcollection1Data.value = value;
}
` try with this line of code

Comment: Hi NIKUNJ KOTHIYA
       console.log(props.sounds) get  empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then((values) => {
        collection1Data.value = values[0].data
        collection2Data.value = values[1].data
        .... 
     }
```

Comment: Hi ΑΓΡΙΑ ΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: values is not defined
    at fetchData   but why we select only values[0] or values[1]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: But this is an other way, use await or .then...  I think that the problem is at: const computed = {...}  This is not the Vue's computed: but just a const of...

Answer (score 0):

I change a code and it work Maybe it can help some people but i not full under stand it  some time you can get code from somewhere and adjust it until it work for you

```
<template>
  <div>
    <CommunicateVo v-if="filenames.value && filenames.value[0]" :files="filenames.value"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref, computed } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import CommunicateVo from './CommunicateVo.vue';

const lands = ref([]);
const filenames = ref([]);

onMounted(async () => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("https://koh-abx.com:46789/oldest-record");
// lands.value =  res.data.oldestRecord.numbershow;
// lands.value = 342;
// lands.value = [342];
      lands.value = res.data.oldestRecord.numbershow.toString().split('');

//       filenames.value = computed(() => {
//       return lands.value.map(item => {
//       const digits = item.toString().split('');
//       return digits.map(digit => `https://koh-abx.com/sound/${digit}.mp3`);
//     });
//     });
    
//     filenames.value = computed(() => {
//   return lands.value.map(item => {
//     const digits = item.toString().split('');
//     return digits.map(digit => `https://koh-abx.com/sound/${digit}.mp3`);
//   });
// });
    
filenames.value = computed(() => {
  return lands.value.map(digit => {
    return `https://koh-abx.com/sound/${digit}.mp3`;
  });
});


    console.log(filenames);
    return filenames;
  };

  fetchData();
  setInterval(fetchData, 200000);
});
</script>

child

<template>
    <div>
      <audio ref="audioEl" />
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
  
  export default {
    props: {
      files: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
      },
    },
    setup(props) {
      const audioEl = ref(null);
      const currentFileIndex = ref(0);
  
    onMounted(() => {
        if (!props.files || props.files.length === 0) {
            return;
        }
        audioEl.value = new Audio();
        audioEl.value.addEventListener("ended", playNextFile);
        document.body.appendChild(audioEl.value);
        audioEl.value.src = props.files[currentFileIndex.value];
        audioEl.value.play();
        });

  
      function playNextFile() {
        currentFileIndex.value += 1;
        if (currentFileIndex.value === props.files.length) {
          document.body.removeChild(audioEl.value);
          return;
        }
        audioEl.value.src = props.files[currentFileIndex.value];
        audioEl.value.play();
      }
  
      return {
        audioEl,
        playNextFile,
      };
    },
  };
  </script>
```